# Website pages not opening other than homepage with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have set up a website on nginx server block and it's loading fine. But as soon as try to open any webpage other than homepage, it shows 404 Not Found message. Due to this none of the pages are viewable other than the homepage.

Here is `sites-available` file.

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;

        root /var/www/yoalfaaz.com/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name yoalfaaz.com www.yoalfaaz.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
        }
}
```

Can you please tell what's the issue that none of the pages is opening. I have also used `nginx -t` and everything goes successful and there are no errors in error.log file.

Comment: I think your error is related to file permissions, although I'd rather recommend to troubleshoot it by enabling server logs. Could you add this lines below `server name`?   `access_log /var/log/nginx/access.http.log detailed;`
`error_log /var/log/nginx/error.http.log notice;`

Comment: @AlvaroNiño thanks for your time. I added the lines as you said and then tried `nginx -t` and this message shows up.
`nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "detailed" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoalfaaz.com:11`
`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Does the path you are trying to access exist?

Comment: @MichaelHampton definitely it exists. Even you can visit the website and try to open any post but none are opening, but on the previous hosting, they all worked.

Comment: Sorry, use access log with combined format as `access_log /var/log/nginx/access.http.log combined;`

Comment: @AlvaroNiño I tried your method but there were no errors in access.http.log file. May be due to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;` which I posted in `sites-available` file. But now the problem is that website links are not opening properly. I click some link and it opens something else and sometimes it just opens the homepage. Can you please take a look at yoalfaaz.com

Answer (score 0):

Change your `location` block from this

```
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

to this

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    # only uncomment the next line, if not set in fastcgi-php.conf already
    # fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

btw: there seems to be another issue on your page: Check connection timeout for your file https://www.yoalfaaz.com/yoimg/yoalfaaz.png

Comment: I don't believe the problem is in PHP configuration, even he didn't mention any PHP web configuration

Comment: Thanks for your time. I added the lines you mentioned above, then tried `nginx -t`  and got this message `nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoalfaaz.com:24 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

The issue about that image is that, it's linked as https in the website and I haven't added SSL on this hosting just yet. So after I solve the first problem then I can go for the second one.

Comment: Looks like your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`file also contains a line `fastcgi_index`. I'm not sure why it is there, because I would use this directive in a server/location context only. If you don't host any other websites on your sever, you could remove this line in nginx.conf. If the problem persists, please past the content of your files `nginx.conf` and snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`.

Comment: Actually, I plan to add another website to my hosting once this website starts to work. Although if you say then I can add `nginx.conf` file to the question description so that you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Those paths *do not exist* as files in the filesystem. They are handled by your web application. But, you are not actually routing them there in `try_files`. You instead are routing them to a 404 page.

```
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Instead, you should be routing requests which aren't static files to your web application. For example:

```
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your answer and replaced the lines with the one you suggested. After that I run the command `nginx -t` and it shows this error `nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "detailed" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoalfaaz.com:11
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: @GurjyotSingh That's because you followed [someone else's advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/898450/website-pages-not-opening-other-than-homepage-with-nginx/898470?noredirect=1#comment1161372_898450) and you did not revert it back to what it was before.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and really sorry for that idiotic mistake. I reverted that other person's advice and now actually that 404 Not Found message is gone but now when I open any post then, the homepage opens with a completely broken layout. Is it due to website files or due to some nginx config?

Comment: Hello, can you please tell what the problem can be? After trying your answer, 404 error is surely gone, but the links are not opening properly. Moreover, most of the times, if I click a link then homepage opens again.